# RMAN incremental restore

Tags: backup, oracle-11g-r2, restore, linux

Can you anyone tell me if it's possible to restore an 11g Oracle database using media management software like Net Backup or Commvault incrementally?

I need to perform a restore of a DB into a new target database (overwriting the DB) ... this of course is fine - connect to the RMAN catalog and then duplicate the DB. However I would then, perhaps 5 days later, like to apply all the incremental changes that occurred on the source to this new target. Is it possible to restore again but only apply the logs from the previous 5 days and roll forward? The new target can be left mounted during this time. It's not being used until all logs are applied. The idea is to save time restoring a massive database before switching over to it permanently. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible. I have done this dozens of times.
It is a simple `RESTORE`, then a `RECOVER` phase 5 days later. Or you can even run `RECOVER` periodically to keep the copy up to date.

Just make sure you do not mess up the catalog with the copy database. Usually I just restore the latest controlfile and use without a catalog connection to prevent RMAN registering restored copies of datafiles in the catalog.

Or use `DUPLICATE` if you want to use Data Guard as suggested.

Comment: If I use the simple redirected restore (delaying the recover phase) method like you mentioned to a different host (I assume I can't use duplicate), 5 days later I need to restore the latest control file and I can simply ìssue the restore and recover commands and only the changes since the last restore will be applied?

Answer (score -1):

With RMAN you would need to re-duplicate the entire database. To achieve the effect you're looking for you would need to set up Data Guard replication. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/solutions/reduce-database-migration-downtime/learn-migrating-oracle-data-guard1.html#GUID-4371514B-17CA-4FC9-94FF-CF8AA16F1C8A

Comment: Thanks for reply. That's what I was afraid of. We have no direct connection to the source DB unfortunately so the restore can only come from the backup pieces on tape. Can't restore to disk first either. What's the accepted best approach for restoring very large DBs (more than 50TB) as fast as possible?

Comment: You're going to have to stop the source DB applications, do a full backup, move your tapes and catalog them into the new backup system, then run the restore and recovery operation. Speed is going to depend almost entirely on your backup media and hardware; In my experience actual tape backups aren't particularly fast. If there's any way to do multipart/parallel backup sets and parallel restoration threads with your tape hardware that would be ideal. I would get in a couple of practice runs so you have a good idea how much time you'll need before the final migration.

Comment: Check this out for a configuration example: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/bradv/configuring-rman-client-advanced.html#GUID-F4DDECAD-AC08-4BBF-A27C-2E045BF89366